# How do I find the exact value of an expression with physical constants

Tags: mathematica

I want to find the exact value for Rydberg constant, so I Type

```
N[(1/(4*pi *eO))^2     * ((m *e^4)/((h)^3*c (4 pi)))] ;
Needs[Miscellaneous`PhysicalConstants` ];
values = {e -> ElectronCharge, m -> ElectronMass, 
   eO -> ElectricConstant, h -> PlanckConstantReduced, 
   c -> SpeedOfLight};
```

and the program shows `(0.015625 e^4 m)/(c eO^2 h^3 pi^3)`.

What should I do in order to find the numerical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is three commands.  You discard the output of all of them.  What did you expect to happen?

Related:  You appear to be using an old version of the software.  The [PhysicalConstants](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PhysicalConstants/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html) package was made part of the core language in version 9.0 ([November 2012](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2012/11/mathematica-9-is-released-today/)).

In the current version (11.2),

```
values = {
    e -> Quantity["ElementaryCharge"], 
    m -> Quantity["ElectronMass"], 
    eO -> Quantity["ElectricConstant"], 
    h -> Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"], 
    c -> Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]
};

UnitConvert[
    (1/(4*\[Pi]*eO))^2*((m*e^4)/((h)^3*c (4 \[Pi]))) /. 
        values, 
    1/"Meters"
]

(*  Result:
    Quantity[1.097373*10^7, 1/("Meters")]  
*)
```